# FFT-based 2D convolution and correlation in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, signal-processing, fft

Is there a FFT-based 2D cross-correlation or convolution function built into scipy (or another popular library)?

There are functions like these:

- `scipy.signal.correlate2d` - "the direct method implemented by `convolveND` will be
  slow for large data"
- `scipy.ndimage.correlate` - "The array is correlated with the given kernel using
  exact calculation (i.e. not FFT)."
- `scipy.fftpack.convolve.convolve`, which I don't really understand, but seems wrong

numarray had a [`correlate2d()` function with an `fft=True` switch](http://structure.usc.edu/numarray/node61.html), but I guess numarray was folded
into numpy, and I can't find if this function was included.

Comment: note that using exact calculation (no FFT) is exactly the same as saying it is slow :) More exactly, the FFT-based method will be much faster if you have a signal and a kernel of approximately the same size (if the kernel is much smaller than the input, then FFT may actually be slower than the direct computation).

Comment: Ideally, the FFT algorithm would automatically take care of zero-padding things to the right size for best speed.

Comment: Oh you're not talking about zero padding, you're talking about matching a 5x5 image with a 2000x2000 image.  Why can't the algorithm just guess whether the FFT would be more efficient and do it whichever way is faster?

Comment: scipy has an fftconvolve function

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`, [as also pointed out by magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1477259/125507), but didn't realize at the time that it's *n*-dimensional.  Since it's built-in and produces the right values, it seems like the ideal solution.

From [Example of 2D Convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html):

```
In [1]: a = asarray([[ 1, 2, 3],
   ...:              [ 4, 5, 6],
   ...:              [ 7, 8, 9]])

In [2]: b = asarray([[-1,-2,-1],
   ...:              [ 0, 0, 0],
   ...:              [ 1, 2, 1]])

In [3]: scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b, mode = 'same')
Out[3]: 
array([[-13., -20., -17.],
       [-18., -24., -18.],
       [ 13.,  20.,  17.]])
```

Correct!  The STSCI version, on the other hand, requires some extra work to make the boundaries correct?

```
In [4]: stsci.convolve2d(a, b, fft = True)
Out[4]: 
array([[-12., -12., -12.],
       [-24., -24., -24.],
       [-12., -12., -12.]])
```

(The STSCI method also requires compiling, which I was unsuccessful with (I just commented out the non-python parts), has some bugs like [this](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/973) and modifying the inputs ([1, 2] becomes [[1, 2]]), etc.  So I changed my accepted answer to the built-in `fftconvolve()` function.)

Correlation, of course, is the same thing as convolution, but with one input reversed:

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])

In [6]: b
Out[6]: 
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [7]: scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b[::-1, ::-1])
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  9.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.]])

In [8]: scipy.signal.correlate2d(a, b)
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 6, 9, 0, 0],
       [2, 4, 6, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]])
```

and [the latest revision](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/scipy/signal/signaltools.py?rev=5968) has been sped up by using power-of-two sizes internally (and then I sped it up more by [using real FFT for real input](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/337) and [using 5-smooth lengths instead of powers of 2](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3144)  :D ).

Answer (score 8):

look at scipy.signal.fftconvolve, signal.convolve and signal.correlate (there is a signal.correlate2d but it seems to return an shifted array, not centered).

Comment: I changed my accepted answer to this, as explained below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100100/fft-based-2d-convolution-and-correlation-in-python/1768140#1768140

Comment: Hi, just an unrelated query.
How long does correlate2d take to run for 2-d arrays of shape 2048x2048?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want the scipy.stsci package:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stsci.html

```
In [30]: scipy.__version__
Out[30]: '0.7.0'

In [31]: from scipy.stsci.convolve import convolve2d, correlate2d
```

Comment: I saw that, too, but it doesn't seem to be included in SciPy anymore?

>>> import scipy.stsci.convolve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named convolve

Comment: Hi - I pasted the output from my prompt above.  What's your version?

Comment: Clearly something is wrong:

http://pastebin.com/mdd2bc6d

Good to know it exists, though.

Comment: Werid.  From your ipython prompt, I see you're using python 2.6.  I have python 2.5.2.  I have no idea why scipy would have a different release per version.  Maybe it's easier to just re-install scipy and see if the problem persists?

Comment: It works on my Windows machine with 2.6, but not on other Ubuntu machines, so it must be a packaging issue with Ubuntu.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/397217

Comment: you could use correlate2d from scipy.signal: it uses more or less the same implementation technique as the stsci.convolve one (no FFT). The 2.6 problem is weird - may be related to a distutils thing.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a cross-correlation/convolution wrapper that takes care of padding & nans and includes a simple smooth wrapper [here](http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/AG_fft_tools/convolve_nd.py).  It's not a popular package, but it also has no dependencies besides numpy (or fftw for faster ffts).

I've also implemented an FFT speed testing code [here](http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/tests/test_ffts.py) in case anyone's interested.  It shows - surprisingly - that numpy's fft is faster than scipy's, at least on my machine.

EDIT: moved code to N-dimensional version [here](http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/AG_fft_tools/convolve_nd.py)

Answer (score 3):

I've lost track of the status of this package in scipy, but I know we include ndimage as part of the stsci_python release package as a convenience for our users:

http://www.stsci.edu/resources/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python/current/download

or you should be able pull it from the repository if you prefer:

https://www.stsci.edu/svn/ssb/stsci_python/stsci_python/trunk/ndimage/

Comment: According to SciPy docs it's not FFT-based, though, as I mentioned in the question.  http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Ndimage

Comment: The convolve package is also available from the stsci_python repository. It includes the correlate2d function that has the fft=True switch that you also mentioned. https://www.stsci.edu/svn/ssb/stsci_python/stsci_python/trunk/convolve/lib/Convolve.py

Comment: Oh!  I can just import that python file directly, if I remove the reference to _correlate.  The FFT correlation is all in Python.  Now I've got it working. :)  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out stsci is being removed from SciPy (which is why it doesn't work) and the stsci_python version is now the authoritative one, so I'm moving this to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, the 1-D convolve/correlate is not FFT-accelerated.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is [scipy.signal.oaconvolve](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.oaconvolve.html#scipy.signal.oaconvolve) since Scipy 1.4, which uses the [Overlap-add method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method).