# Correlate a large image with a kernel in python using numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have an image (10000x10000 pixels) and I have a kernel (5x5 pixels). I want to find the place(s) in the image that best matches the kernel.

I vaguely remember from my studies that I need to compute a correlation coefficient for each pixel in the large image with respect to the kernel. But having something like (10000 - 4) * (10000 - 4) pixels to go through, I expect to get a huge performance hit doing this in `python`.

Having only a very brief knowledge on the subject I was hoping to find something in either `numpy` or `scipy` that would do this relatively fast, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Does either `numpy` or `scipy` contain a method for doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100100/fft-based-2d-convolution-and-correlation-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This is usually referred to as **template matching** in image processing and most image processing packages will have something for it.  If you can use scikit-image then you probably want [`match_template`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html).  Of course, OpenCV can do [template matching too](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv2.matchTemplate).

If you need to stick with pure scipy, it's easy enough to implement yourself: just find the maximum pixel (`argmax`) of a normalized cross-correlation (`correlate2d`).

Comment: scikit-image link is barroquen