# Computing wrapped 2D correlation with fftconvolve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, correlation

I have a set of of 2D arrays that I have to compute the 2D correlation of. I have been trying many different things (even programming it in Fortran), but I think the fastest way will be calculating it using FFT.

Based on my tests and on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768140) I can use `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` and it works fine if I'm trying to reproduce the output of `scipy.signal.correlate2d` with `boundary='fill'`. So basically this

```
scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, a[::-1, ::-1], mode='same')
```

is equal to this (with the exception of a slight shift)

```
scipy.signal.correlate2d(a, a, boundary='fill', mode='same')
```

The thing is that the arrays should be computed in wrapped mode, since they are 2D periodic arrays (i.e., `boundary='wrap'`). So if I'm trying to reproduce the output of

```
scipy.signal.correlate2d(a, a, boundary='wrap', mode='same')
```

I can't, or at least I don't see how to do it. (And I want to use the FFT method, since it's way faster.)

Apparently Scipy used to have [something like that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stsci.convolve.correlate2d.html) that might have done the trick, but apparently it got left behind and I can't find it, so I think Scipy might have dropped support for it.

Anyway, is there a way to use `scipy`'s or `numpy`'s FFT routines to calculate this correlation of period arrays?

Comment: how does your `a` look like?

Comment: @kmario23 It's private experimental data so I can't really share here. But it's 200x200 arrays that are periodic in x and y.

Comment: I don't have a good answer at the moment, but that "left behind" code you mentioned can be found [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.7.x/scipy/stsci/convolve/lib/Convolve.py#L144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrapped correlation can be implemented using the FFT.  Here's some code to demonstrate how:

```
In [276]: import numpy as np

In [277]: from scipy.signal import correlate2d
```

Create a random array `a` to work with:

```
In [278]: a = np.random.randn(200, 200)
```

Compute the 2D correlation using `scipy.signal.correlate2d`:

```
In [279]: c = correlate2d(a, a, boundary='wrap', mode='same')
```

Now compute the same result, using the 2D FFT functions from `numpy.fft`. (This code assumes `a` is square.)

```
In [280]: from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2

In [281]: fc = np.roll(ifft2(fft2(a).conj()*fft2(a)).real, (a.shape[0] - 1)//2, axis=(0,1))
```

Verify that both methods give the same result:

```
In [282]: np.allclose(c, fc)
Out[282]: True
```

And as you point out, using the FFT is *much* faster.  For this example, it is about 1000 times faster:

```
In [283]: %timeit c = correlate2d(a, a, boundary='wrap', mode='same')
1 loop, best of 3: 3.2 s per loop

In [284]: %timeit fc = np.roll(ifft2(fft2(a).conj()*fft2(a)).real, (a.shape[0] - 1)//2, axis=(0,1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.19 ms per loop
```

And that includes the duplicated computation of `fft2(a)`.  Of course, `fft2(a)` should only be computed once:

```
In [285]: fta = fft2(a)

In [286]: fc = np.roll(ifft2(fta.conj()*fta).real, (a.shape[0] - 1)//2, axis=(0,1))
```